# What does Windows 10 Pro do behind my back?

Tags: windows-10, monitoring

I have a Dell notebook running Windows 10 Pro, up-to-date as of today May 10, 2021.

Starting 4-6 weeks ago, when I lock the screen and go away, this PC starts working. When I go back to work, I find the fans spinning and the PC hot.

To understand which apps are responsible of this, I deleted the App History in the Task Manager. It did not solve the mystery. Please see this screenshot:

[image]

The apps I use the most are not listed. It seems that only apps installed from the Windows Store end up in that listing.

It could be a virus, but many scans did not detect anything. I have already disable the "Windows Telemetry".

Is there anyone who can suggest a monitoring tool/built-in way able to produce a real and useful report on app CPU usage?

Comment: I don't think you understand Windows 10 at all. Telemetry is not a plot. If transmits aggregate data (not personal data) to fix problems. Do not disable it. You cannot delete an app by deleting the App History. Use Programs and Features to uninstall things there or Power Shell to uninstall Windows 10 Store apps you do not want. Run a Full Scan with Windows Defender to check for viruses.

Comment: "It could be a virus" - It's not a virus.  By the way you cannot fully disable Windows Telemetry on Windows 10.  You can only (by default) only set it to the lowest setting.  You can uninstall most of the applications in your screenshot.

Comment: Most likely this is background virus scanning, disk optimisation, and general housekeeping. Some updates also need a lot of disk preparation and download time, most of which will happen in the background. The "App history" tab only shows UWP apps and not the vast majority of "normal" applications that make up windows and is nearly useless for diagnosing the system. You should be looking at the "Processes" or "Details" tabs in task manager. [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) might be a good tool to see more details.

Comment: Most likely the process is still running, therefore just go to the "Detail" tab and add the "CPU-Time" column and sort by it descending. Then you will see the running processes that have used a lot of CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound I followed this answer on the microsoft forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/permanently-disabling-windows-compatibility/6bf71583-81b0-4a74-ae2e-8fd73305aad1#:~:text=On%20the%20TaskScheduler%20window%2C%20go,confirm%20to%20complete%20the%20process. Sometimes the process Telemetry started in the middle of a computation slowing down everything. I have never seen it again. I know I can uninstall them, but I was curious to know why the applications I use are not listed.

Comment: @Robert I obviously go and check those tabs (I use also process explorer), but cannot find anything using plenty of cpu (that I am not aware of). It is like a processed is stopped as soon as I type my password.That's why I thought of using App History, I did not know it tracks only UWP apps.

Comment: Process start and ending can be traced using Sysinternal Process Monitor. Just disable registry, network and file events.

Comment: @AntonioSesto - Those instructions are out of date.  Windows will just automatically enable that scheduled task eventually.